# JavaFX - Trouble with creating tabs

Tags: java, tabs, javafx, fxml

I want that when pressing the "accept" button created new tab.
But throw exceptions. I try create command class (CreateTab class) but unfortunately all the same.

**Tabs**

```
    public class Tabs implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    TabPane tabPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        try {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            //tabPane.getTabs().addAll((Tab) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("main.fxml")));
            tab.setContent((Node) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("connectLayout.fxml")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createTab(String name){
        try {
            Tab tab = new Tab(name);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            tab.setContent((Node) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("main.fxml")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

**ConnectView**

Here devilish button))

```
public class ConnectView implements Initializable {

    // Create
    @FXML
    TextField chatName;


    // Create chat
    @FXML
    public void accept(){
        String chatName = this.chatName.getText();
        //String limit = this.limit.getText();

        Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.createTab(chatName);

    }
}
```

Some exceptions

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1456)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at View.Tabs.createTab(Tabs.java:34)
    at View.ConnectView.accept(ConnectView.java:63)
```

Comment: What is line 34 of Tabs.java?

Comment: line 34 because i've cut some unnecessary code.

Comment: `tabPane` is going to be `null` when you call `tabs.createTab()`. `Tabs` looks like a controller class; the `FXMLLoader` for the associated FXML file will create an instance of `Tabs` and initialize the `@FXML`-annotated fields, namely `tabPane`. However, from `ConnectView` you create a **new** `Tabs` instance, which is not created by the `FXMLLoader`, and the `tabPane` field in that instance is never initialized. You need to arrange for your `ConnectView` to have a reference to the `Tabs` instance that was created by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: I think @jewelsea was asking which actual line in your posted code is line 34 in your actual code. (I'm guessing it's `tabPane.getTabs().addTab(...)` in the `createTab` method, but it would be nice if you would confirm that.)